# Creating Design Document

Tags: java, architecture, microservices

In my organization, I have received the task of creating a Design Document.

**Task Description:**

It is a monolithic Java module and I need to convert it into a microservice. This means I need to check what all dependencies are there in this module. How these dependencies will be removed? How much effort it requires.

**Question is**: I have been asked to create the design document first for this monolithic-to-microservice-conversion task. I don't know what shall I put inside the design document?

Can anybody help me with what should I mention in the design document for this task?

I have not created any design document before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some aspects that you can think of:

- The initiative - a few phrases where you describe the main idea of the project described by that design doc, with some general guidelines (e.g. We want to convert this monolithic system, into a microservice-based one, because of X, Y and Z)
- Expose the existing architecture of the service, with all the dependencies that it has to other modules / components. A diagram would really help here.
- Expose the desired state of the system, how the microservice fits into the new architecture (same as above, a diagram is needed here)
- Break down the steps you need to take to reach that state. The exact changes you need to make to reach the final output. You can explicitly mention which ones depend on each other, and which do not. In that way you know which ones can be executed by different team members. You can put them in a table or in a bulleted list)
- Give some estimations around those steps - how many days / hours it would take to finalize them.